# Select item from HtmlSelect that contains some string

Tags: html, asp.net, select

I have select. As you might see, text is different from value.

```
<select id="divPlatformsPopup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" class="selectpicker col-md-12 ClassPad0" multiple title='Choose one of the following...' data-container="body" data-selected-text-format="count>2" data-style="btn-xs btn-default">
        <option value="All">All Platforms</option>
        <option value="Mobile Phone,Tablet,Windows Phone,PlayStation Certified Device,Windows 8 App,PlayStation Mobile">Mobile App/Tablet</option>
        <option value="Nintendo DS,Nintendo DSi,Nintendo 3DS">Nintendo DS/DSi/3DS</option>
        <option value="Playstation 3">Playstation 3</option>
        <option value="PlayStation 4">PlayStation 4</option>
        <option value="PSP,PS Vita">PlayStation Vita/PSP</option>
        <option value="Wii">Wii</option>
        <option value="Wii U">Wii U</option>
        <option value="Linux,Macintosh,PC DVD,PC DVD-ROM,Windows CE,Windows PC,Windows 8 App">Windows/Mac</option>
        <option value="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</option>
        <option value="Xbox One">Xbox One</option>
        <option value="3DO,Atari Jaguar,Atari Lynx,Cable Box,CDI,Dreamcast,DVD,Game Boy,Game Boy Advance,Game Boy Color,Game Gear,Game Wave(Custom DVD gaming platform),Game Cube,Gizmondo,Hyperscan,iPod,N-Gage,Neo Geo Pocket Color,Nintendo,Nintendo 64,Nintendo Game Boy,NUON,Online,Other,Palm Pilot,PDA(Palm, Win CE, etc.),PlayStation&2FPS one,Playstation 2,Plug-and-Play,Pocket Arcade,Pocket PC,Pokemon Mini,Sega 32x,Sega CD,Sega Dreamcast,Sega Genesis,Sega Pico,Sega Pocket Arcade,Sega Saturn,Super Nintendo,VG Pocket,Virtual Boy,Web Browser,Web Site,Web TV,Xbox,Zodiac,Firefox">Other Platforms</option>
    </select>
```

And I have part of code to set selected values by value.

```
foreach (var li in platforms.Select(platform => divPlatformsPopup.Items.FindByValue(platform)))
            {
                li.Selected = true;
            }
```

where `platforms` is list of selected values

But here is one case that i didn't count. It's possible to pass into `platforms` list value which is part of value from select (For example "Nintendo DS" as part of "Nintendo DS,Nintendo DSi,Nintendo 3DS").

And i want to know how to select item which contains some part of VALUE of select item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i find solution:

I goes in a loop for every item in Select and check if item contains some string

```
foreach (var platform in platforms)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= divPlatformsPopup.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Array.IndexOf(divPlatformsPopup.Items[i].Value.Split(','), platform) > -1)
                    {
                        divPlatformsPopup.Items[i].Selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```